# Using variables in React setState to move an element from one array to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

So I want to condense 2 functions I have that move an element from one array to another. The arrays being modified need to be variables so I can use this on any 2 arrays.

This is the function I currently have

```
clickedEventHandler = (index, target, origin) => {
  let tempArry = [...origin];
  console.log(tempArry);
  let resultedArry = [...target];

  resultedArry.push(tempArry[index]);
  tempArry.splice((index, 1)[index]);

  console.log(resultedArry);
  console.log(tempArry);

  this.setState({
    addedArry: resultedArry,
    userArry: tempArry
  });
}
```

I'm trying to get an element from the original array and move it to the target array. This means I need to delete it from the origin as well so it's a cut, not a copy.

```
  this.setState({
    addedArry: resultedArry,
    userArry: tempArry
  });
```

I want `addArry` and `userArry` to be variables so I can use target and origin to decide what's going where.

I was told I shouldn't mutate the arrays directly in react so this was my attempt at doing it without mutating.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Manipulating array is wrong when handling the store data of Redux but within a component variable or state manipulation is good to go

Comment: So my plan is to expand this to redux once I know more about it. That's why I'm trying to learn this now. Is what I want even possible?

Comment: I also noticed that in my example, splice leave the temparry empty

Answer (score 2):

The concept is that one must not manipulate the Redux store directly, so in the Redux reducer you can add an item to store array like

```
case ADD_ITEM :
return { 
    ...state,
    arr: state.arr.concat(action.newItem)
}
```

you can remove an item from an array in redux store like

```
case DELETE_ITEM :
    const newState = Object.assign([], state);
    newState.splice(index, 1);
    return newState;
```

we can also use the lodash library and implement

```
import _ from 'lodash';

case ADD_ITEM:
     refArr = _.clone(state.arr);
     refArr.push('data');
     return Object.assign({}, state, {arr: refArr});

case DELETE_ITEM:
     refArr = _.clone(state.arr);
     refArr.splice(index, 1);
     return Object.assign({}, state, {arr: refArr});
```

[Redux reducer doc](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers)

Comment: That's super helpful, thank you so much! I'll give it a shot

Comment: I keep getting - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'arr' of null` does that mean arr is coming in null?

Comment: State is null for some reason

Comment: we have no clue of your code base, please give clarity or provide link to the reducer code @EladKarni

Comment: I'm currently having an issue with my lists, but this should give you an idea of how my redux looks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096939/firebase-react-reducers-seemingly-getting-mixed-info